# how to forward request to https backend

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a website running at https://myexample.com:32437. Now I want to access it with URL https://myexample.com.

I used Nginx as a reverse proxy and tried to configure upstream like

```
upstream cluster{
    server myexample.com:32437;
}

server{
    listen      80;
    server_name myexample.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;

    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  https://cluster;
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

        proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

but this is not working. I am getting "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error in the browser. 
Can anyone please help me with configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you did not set HTTPS listener and valid certificate, because you are trying to establish secure connection to `https://myexample.com`.

And also please note, if you want to proxy pass HTTPS traffic, then an upstream should be configured to accept HTTPS connections.
And since you accept HTTPS connections and then proxying to HTTPS, it’s enough to specify the certificate settings once in the server section.

Add https listener and certificate settings to your config in server section.

```
listen 443 ssl;
ssl_certificate     /path_to_cert/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path_to_key/server.key;
```

Remove those unneeded lines from your config:

```
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
```

Here is the [link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/) which can explain such behavior in more details.

Comment: upstream is already running on https so do i need certificates in this nginix setup also...

Comment: all i want is what ever request comes to the server HTTP or https ,get forwarded to upstream which is listening on https and port is 32437 or you can say upstream SSL port is 32437

Comment: Yea you need to specify certificate in the nginx setup to be able to proxy pass https traffic. If you don't want to enable HTTPS listener, and receive only HTTP requests, then you can specify certificate config at location section, like this:    `proxy_ssl_certificate     /path_to_cert/server.crt;`
`proxy_ssl_certificate_key /path_to_key/server.key;`